# Changing CSS from JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to change the css properties of an element under the condition that the `window.innerWidth` is greater than 750px. I am doing this with Javascript however I am having some difficulties.

I can't see any errors in the code, so has anyone got any suggestions as to what it might be?

Here is what I'm working with:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    if (window.innerWidth > 750) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100vh";   
    } else {
        //do nothing   
    }
});
```

Here is the CSS code for the header that I would like to add the `height` entry for:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #18bc9c;
}
```

Comment: is it going inside `if`?

Comment: I checked with some other html it workes fine.. So can you chaeck if there is element with header as id in your html.. but you say there is no error too

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lefsfu17/1/ Perhaps you should look for problems elsewhere.

Comment: @Abhitalks I will edit my question to show the css for the header I am trying to edit.

Comment: @dwinnbrown: That is also working: http://jsfiddle.net/Lefsfu17/3/ . One suggestion, please try out whatever you are doing in a fiddle and test it out. You will immediately identify where you are going wrong :)

Comment: I noticed you select by ID with your JS and by tagname with your CSS. Maybe that's where things are going wrong? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648450/changing-css-from-js-doesnt-work/31648542#31648542 for how to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're using `document.getElementById("header")`, yet your CSS is defined as `header {...}`. In the first case, your code searches by ID and in the second case it searches by tagname.

Unless your header uses both the header tag and the header ID (`<header id="header">...</header>`), you're probably using one of both wrong:

- If you want to select an element by tagname with your JS, you need to use `document.getElementsByTagName(tagname)` instead.
- If you want to select an element by ID with your CSS, you need to use `#header {...}` instead.

---

Additionally, your case begs the question why are you doing this with Javascript! Why don't you just use a media query? **You should ALWAYS avoid doing this kind of thing with Javascript!**

Media queries are the **default way** to change your styling based on the screen width. They offer the best performance and have great browser support.

If you want to select by ID, try this code:

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #18bc9c;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 751px) {
    #header {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

If you want to select by tagname, try this code:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #18bc9c;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 751px) {
    header {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that `height` needs to be specified already i.e. you can't add a line of css through JS?

Comment: @dwinnbrown : You can add any CSS rule to your page using something like `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule()`. `document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100vh"; ` should work as well, as shown in the JSFiddle in the comments. It's not the proper way to do things for this use case, though. You should really consider using media queries!

Answer (score -2):

I´ve missed a semicolon:

var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

Comment: [semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) rules mean that doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: the code stops in a normal environment if ; is missing

Comment: I have taken that out now and just using `if (window.innerWidth < 750)` still not working

Comment: @ArminBleiholder — A test case was linked to from the comments on the question — http://jsfiddle.net/Lefsfu17/1/ — it shows that it works in a normal environment, even with the semi-colon missing.

Comment: yes you are right - semicolon is in this case not necessary